# run django microservice with while loop?

Tags: python, django, while-loop, microservices

I have a django app running as a microservice. Which has a function which does the following:

1. Checks for filenames matching *.json in a directory.
2. for each file:

   - processes json data and converts to xml.
   - saves xml in target directory.
3. Exits function.

Is there any reason i shouldn't do this to keep it running on a cycle:

```
While True:
    main_function()
```

The previous developer was using threading which i think is making things far too complicated given there's no need to optimise performance.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for this:
http://www.celeryproject.org/

Celery is easy to understand and implement and should not take a lot of time.
Let me know if it helps you.